# What is the mathematical notation for representing a maximum number output?

Tags: notation

For example, something like the following:

```
LowerOfTheTwo(a × b,1000) = c
```

So, if `a = 100` and `b = 2`, then `c = 200`.

But, if `a = 100` and `b = 200`, then `c = 1000`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be thinking of $\min\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$, which gives the smallest element in the set $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$

For example,

$\min\{1,5\}=1$ and $\min\{-23,45,51,93\}=-23$

Comment: So would $\min\{x*y,1000\}=z$ be the correct representation of my example in the question?

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer: Yes, that would be correct.